# libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pycurl, pyspider

ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
i use win10 + py3.9 + pycurl-7.44.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl + i can't use import ,please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69385342/importerror-pycurl-libcurl-link-time-ssl-backends-schannel-do-not-include-co

Comment: Could not report duplicate as the duplicate finder did not locate it

Answer (score 0):

pycurl version
pip install pycurl==7.43.0.5

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.