# ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include compile-time ssl backend (openssl)

Tags: python

Import pycurl ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
My system is Windows 10 and I used python 3.9.7
I used pycurl 7.44.1 By downloading .whl Installed

Tried methods
1.PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
2.pip install pycurl Error Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl Only through By downloading .whl Installed
3.Use lower version Pycurl

Comment: I have answer given here for windows and Mac. You can pick the windows one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888757/importerror-pycurl-libcurl-link-time-ssl-backend-openssl-is-different-from-c/69461885#69461885

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac:
If you are still looking for a proper way to work around this then do the following

Step 1: Uninstall PyCurl

```
pip uninstall pycurl
```

Step 2: Reinstall Open SSL using Brew

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

Copy the location of **CPPFLAGS** and **LDFLAGS** which will be prompted to you while installing openssl.

Then Paste those values in the command prompt.

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/brew/openssl/include 
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/brew/openssl/lib # may be needed
```

NOTE: The location of these flags would be different for you, So copy-paste it correctly while reinstalling OpenSSL

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

You should be able to install pycurl without any issues now.

Comment: This results in `error: legacy-install-failure` on arm64 Mac m1.

Comment: What worked for me:
     `PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include" pip3 install --no-cache-dir pycurl`